# I cant retrieve what is inside my outlook with my code

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I can't get the inside on my Task folder on my outlook with my code. Do you guys know any problems here?

The problem I saw is that it doesnt go in my For Loop.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer


Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Task")


i = 1

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range(“date_received”).Value Then
Range(“Sender”).Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
Range(“Sender”).Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
Range(“Sender”).Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
Range(“Body”).Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
Range(“Body”).Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
Range(“Body”).Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop

i = i + 1
End If
Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed few things on your code but it's working allright for me

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant
    Dim i As Integer

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Bienvenidas")

    i = 2

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("MySheet") 'Change MySheet for your sheet name, and ALWAYS reference sheets and workbooks.
        For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
            If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= .Range("C1") Then
                With .Cells(i, 1)
                    .Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
                    .Columns.AutoFit
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
                End With
                With .Cells(i, 2)
                    .Value = OutlookMail.Body
                    .Columns.AutoFit
                    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
                End With
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next OutlookMail
    End With

    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Instead of using ranges and then offseting, go to the cell which have the sender, body and date range and reference them directly.

The only thing that comes to me, is that folder "tasks" inside your inbox folder? The error may come from there.

Edit: Code to check all your subfolders inside the inbox folder:

```
Sub Loop_folders_of_inbox()

    Dim ns As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim myfolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim mysubfolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set ns = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    'Get the default inboxfolder
    Set myfolder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    'Loop through each folder and display name of the folder
    For Each mysubfolder In myfolder.Folders
        Debug.Print mysubfolder.Name
    Next mysubfolder

End Sub
```

Edit 2: Each word from the body into a different column:

```
Dim arrBody
Dim j As Long

arrBody = Split(OutlookMail.Body, " ") 'words delimited by space
For j = LBound(arrBody) To UBound(arrBody)
    .Cells(i, j + 1) = arrBody(j) 'use j + 1 because arrays built from Space function start at index 0
Next j
```

Comment: Is your Bienvenidas folder a sub folder of your inbox?

Comment: Yes, are you looking for the default folder called task? If so, you want `(olFolderTasks)`

Comment: my Task folder is a subfolder in my Inbox folder. Is my code right on that part?

Comment: Yes, in theory... I edited my answer adding a code to check all your subfolders inside the inbox. If the immediate window shows you the "Task" folder, then it must be empty....

Comment: Glad it helped, Consider marking this as correct answer so others might find it.

Comment: hey man, do you happen to know how to do it if every word in the mail get pasted in a different cell going to the right?

Comment: @Link look at my second edit, beware of the lenght on your mails because columns have a limit and the code splits words by spaces.

Comment: ill rephrase it. how to copy table from outlook then paste it as table in excel using your code?

Comment: Read [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/5225-export-outlook-email-body-table-to-excel.html) @Link it might help you.